# Point cloud, cluster, blob detection

Tags: matlab, opencv, cluster-analysis, point-clouds

I have a binary image full noises. I detected the objects circled in red using median filter `B = medfilt2(A, [m n])`(Matlab) or `medianBlur(src, dst, ksize)`(openCV). 
Could you suggest other methods to detect those objects in a more "academic" way,  e.g probabilistic method, clustering, etc?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example looks like the very scenario DBSCAN was designed for.
Lots of noise, but with a well understood density, and clusters with much higher density but arbitrary shape.

Comment: i think that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sort of clustering here and can start from k-means one. 
You can find a pretty good example from [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html?prodcode=IP&language=en) to start with.

Comment: k-means is not very robust wrt. noise.